# Using windows azure authetication for mobile services

Tags: facebook, azure, twitter, windows-phone, windows-live-id

I making windows phone apps and i find out that windows azure have "identity" feature to authenticate user and getting userID,
what i want to know is:

1. can i use this userID to identify each user that login? (my app allow user to post a comment into the app and i looking for using this userID for tracking each user comment)
2. can i retrieve other data beside userID? like display name or picture and is it same like using their native sdk? (facebook or twitter)? to post into timeline?
3. My first approach is trying to integrate microsoft account but i don't know where to get client id and client secret

sorry for many question, i just getting very confuse about this... and after hours of watching channel9 and reading i just barely understand any of this...

Answer (score 0):

have a look at the following blog posts using Azure Mobile Services and see if it helps you:

[Getting user information on Azure Mobile Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2012/10/25/getting-user-information-on-azure-mobile-services.aspx)

[Enhanced users feature in Azure Mobile Services](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/carlosfigueira/archive/2013/12/16/enhanced-users-feature-in-azure-mobile-services.aspx)

Comment: oh is it still valid, i see these article already more then 1 years old

Comment: should still be valid. the second one is the latest update on the User object (dec 2013)